# I need to write a java program that continuously prompts the user to enter a sentence. then reverse string only exit if stop entered

Tags: java

Here is what I have so far, I think I might need an infinity loop which I don't know how to implement:

I need to write a Java program that continuously prompts the user to enter a sentence, and then reverse the string. The exit should happen only if 'stop' is entered

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Reverse 
{


    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println("Plaese enter a sentence:");

        Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str = read.nextLine();
        String reverse = "";


        for(int i = str.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            reverse = reverse + str.charAt(i);


        }

        System.out.println("Please enter a sentence:");
        System.out.println(reverse);    

    }

}
```

Comment: You can make an "Infinite" loop with either `while (true) {...}`, `do {...} while (true);`, or `for(;;) {...}`; pick your favorite.  My personal preference, though would be to have something like `boolean stopping = false; while (!stopping) {...}` and set the `stopping` flag to `true` somewhere inside the loop.

Comment: while we're going with personal favorites, `boolean run = true; for (;run;) { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

You can use both `while` or `for` loop for infinite loop. Also there can be two ways to terminate the program:

1. User can enter `end of file marker`. eg: `Ctrl + z` on linux.
2. Some termination condition recognised by the program.

Here is sample code:

```
    import java.util.Scanner; 
    public class Reverse {
        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
           while(true) {
               System.out.println("Please enter a sentence, Type Stop to exit the program ");
               Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
               String str = read.nextLine();
               if( str.equalsIgnoreCase("stop")) {
                  System.exit(0);
               }
               String reverse = "";
               for(int i = str.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    reverse = reverse + str.charAt(i);
               }        
               System.out.println(reverse);
         }
      }
  }
```

Comment: You are a genius sir,  but you explain this line to me "String str = read.nextLine();" is this a standard command to print out the next line?

Answer (score 0):

Use `while(true)` for looping infinitely. Check for every input string and break out of the loop if the input equals 'exit'. You can also use StringBuilder's reverse method instead to reverse the string.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    String input;
    Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);

    while ( true )
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter a sentence:");

        input = read.nextLine();

        if ("exit".equalsIgnoreCase(input))
        {
            break;
        }

        // reverse a string
        System.out.println(new StringBuilder(input).reverse().toString());
    }
}
```